# Adding additional field to registration form in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento

i was using this tutorial to add additional field in Magento 1.9 in Registration form: http://www.fontis.com.au/blog/magento/know-more-about-your-customers-adding-custom-signup-attributes

But unfortunately it not works. I am new in Magento and need some help. I would appreciate step by step instruction on how to create new module in order to be able to add this additional field in current registration form Magento 1.9.

Comment: I followed all steps on above link. Created initial xml file so that magento could recognise my local module and created main config xml file and other files as well. 

Overall i thought i could see some changes in database and thought there will be created additional table for my new attributes,  but could not find them. That's why i am not sure whether it works correct or not. And i didn't know how to get user info received by user. So any help or explanation would be appreciated. I just stuck here and can not move further.

Comment: Did you found any tutorial? I Need some help with this.

Comment: all new modules are listed in table core_resource. can you find your module? you have to disable your cache or refresh all caches.

Comment: No, my modules doesn't listed in core_resource table. I followed this tutorial and doesn't work.http://magentoabid.blogspot.com.es/2012/08/how-to-add-custom-field-in-one-page.html?showComment=1414078639721#c2258329570472079874

Answer (score 17):

Ok, I just did it, here is how.
Go to http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/ and using its Module Creator to create a new module called "YourCustomerAttribute".

1. Set "Add Customer Attribute" to YES
2. Make proper inputs and selections as you needed.
3. Make sure to select the forms you needed the new attributes to be used.
4. Generate the module.
5. Upload the module to your Magento folder.
6. Modify  located at app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/customer/form/register.phtml and add:

   ```
    <div class="input-box">
    <label for="YourAttributeName"><?php echo $this->__('YourAttributeName') ?><span class="required">*</span></label><br />
    <input type="text" name="YourAttributeName" id="YourAttributeID" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getFormData()->getYourAttributeName()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('YourAttributeName') ?>" class="required-entry input-text" />
   </div>
   ```
7. If you want customer to be able to modify the attribute in customer panel, then modify app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/form/edit.phtm and add:

   ```
   <li>
       <label for="YourAttributeName" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('YourAttributeName') ?></label>
       <div class="input-box">
           <input type="text" name="YourAttributeName" id="YourAttributeID" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCustomer()->getYourAttributeName()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('YourAttributeName') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" />
       </div>
   </li>
   ```
8. Refresh all caches.

Comment: How can I display select list?

Comment: Is there any way of displaying the field in the registration form without editing the theme files

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it **manually**, directly via **SQL** because you only need a quick fix, here is how the values are stored in the DB for **Magento 1.9** (might work for M2).

> This is not good practice as it is a direct DB manipulation that won't work if you move your theme to another server without using the same DB. There are some use cases in which this might be warranted though ;)

1. Add a new entry into the '*eav_attribute*' table, in this case, to have a checkbox, use

   ```
   INSERT INTO `eav_attribute`
     (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_code`, `attribute_model`, `backend_model`, `backend_type`, `backend_table`, `frontend_model`, `frontend_input`, `frontend_label`, `frontend_class`, `source_model`, `is_required`, `is_user_defined`, `default_value`, `is_unique`, `note`)
   VALUES
     ( 1,  'gdpr_accept',  NULL,   NULL,   'int',  NULL,   NULL,   'select',   'GDPR', NULL,   'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',  1,  1,  '0',    0,  NULL);
   ```

   This will add a checkbox entry with the name '*gdpr_accept*' (to be used in the form html later) and the title '*GDPR*' (will be used when referring to it).
2. Add a new entry to 'customer_eav_attribute', using the attribute_id of the entry you created in 1.

   ```
   INSERT INTO `customer_eav_attribute`
     (`attribute_id`, `is_visible`, `input_filter`, `multiline_count`, `validate_rules`, `is_system`, `sort_order`, `data_model`)
   VALUES
     (ATTRIBUTE_ID_FROM_1, 1,  NULL,   0,  NULL,   0,  100,    NULL);
   ```

   This will add the necessary setting to the new value.
3. Add a new entry to the 'customer_form_attribute' table, again with the *attribute_id* from 1.

   ```
   INSERT INTO `customer_form_attribute`
     (`form_code`, `attribute_id`) 
   VALUES
     ('customer_account_create',   ATTRIBUTE_ID_FROM_1);
   ```

   This will tell Magento to check for the new checkbox value when validating the registration form.
4. This step is the same as with the accepted answer, you can now add the checkbox to the form and it will be validated automagically by Magento:

   ```
   <li class="field gdpraccept">
     <div class="input-box">
       <input type="checkbox" id="gdpr_accept" name="gdpr_accept" value="1"
              title="<?php echo $this->__('Accept the privacy policy') ?>" class="checkbox required-entry">
     </div>
     <label for="is_subscribed">
         <?php echo $this->__('Registering you confirm that you accept our  ') ?>
         <a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('cms/page')->getPageUrl( 25 ) ?>">
             <?php echo $this->__('privacy policy'); ?>
         </a>.
     </label>
   </li>
   ```

   Note that in this case the id of the page with the privacy policy is 25, it will probably 
   be different in your case.

This was a simple checkbox case, if you want a different field, with custom validation, have a look at the 'eav_attribute' table, there you can find examples of other fields that have been added.

Or, even better, walk the recommended way and use a module like the http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/ is creating (you can do the same thing they do in your own custom module)